# How do you yank all non-whitespace characters under the cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

I very often find myself doing too many keystrokes to yank/delete all the text that is surrounded by whitespace characters. For example, let's say my cursor is on the 'b' character in the following text:

```
foo = this.that.bar("hello") #Some Comment
```

I want to yank:

```
this.that.bar("hello")
```

I would hope to do something like:

```
yi[space]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [y]ank [i]nner [W]ORD will do:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please press these keys: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

Type: `:help text-objects` to learn more.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help reference too. I now see that w/e/b and W/E/B seem to go hand in hand. I'm surprised that this question hasn't been asked before... or at least not in a way that I could easily find. :-)

Comment: @JavidJamae, that's probably because the answer is easy to find in Vim's `:help`.